# How do you implement a Dock Menu in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

How do you implement a Dock Menu in SwiftUI?

Apple defines "Dock menus" in its [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/menus-and-actions/dock-menus#Resources) but I don't see how to implement it in SwiftUI.  Does someone have an example of how to do it?

Comment: I'm looking for the same info. I tried adding applicationDockMenu(_ : ) to my app delegate, but even though it's called once randomly, it won't work…